# Web application with Cognito sing in method

Tags: javascript, html, css, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have created a simple HTML page, with a header with the logo and a Home link to go back to the home page, and on the body, it has a simple button.

**What I need:**

This button needs to redirect to another HTML page, in this case, is a contact Us page, but I want to enable this page only if the user is logged in. For Sign In/Up purposes, I am using a Cognito User Pool, it is all configured, works fine.

The only issue is, how to make this single button to check if the user is logged in or not. If he is logged in, go to the contact Us page, if not logged in, redirect to the cognito page to sign in/up, and then redirect to contact us page.

**What I have until now**

I made the button to the contact page to redirect to the login page, and then after successful login in, redirect to the contact page. But the problem is, if the user understand a bit about computers, he can manipulate the URL directly on the browser and access the page without login in

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en-US">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Button page</title>
    </head>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <img src="img/askmate.png">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

    <body>
        <a href="contactUs.html"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button></a> // This is the button to either open the contact page or sign in
        
        

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am no Programming Professional. But what you could do is set a variable a give a value when the user has signed in. And create a function which checks if the variable has a value. And execute the function on the click of the function.

Comment: Yeah, so, what I achieved until now is, I made the button to redirect to the login page, and after login in, redirect to the contact page. the problem is, if the user understand a bit about computers, he can manipulate the URL and go to the page without logging in, so now I am trying to do it

Comment: The clever idea would be to get the login on a server side script like Node.js. I don't know much about server side scripts. But you can get some tutorials on youtube and W3schools.

Comment: Thank you! I am already looking into server side scripts, appreciate!